# datagridView.rows.count = 0

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

i know this question maybe a duplicate of others, but i'm losing my mind trying to understand what's going on.
This program of mine loads a list of excel files, and when one of them i selected, i can choose which sheet i want to display with the datagridview.
Now, having  data_ListDisplay as DatagridView populated with 211 rows:
With the code below, i would like to find the colum.index of the first cell in row collection in datagridview which has the given "string" that matches with the search criteria.

However, the row.count is ALWAYS = 0.

Yesterday it was working fine (OFC it was..). Then, i needed to make the datagridview PUBLIC to use the data inside to populate another list (data is elaborate while populating) which belongs to another class.
Code is fine, no error and the line i used to make data_listDisplay puplic is

`public DataGridView DataGridCR { get { return data_ListDisplay; } }`

Hereafter the piece of code (in the original code, the 2 foreach construct belongs to 2 private methods that calculates the variables CrAnalysedCol and CrRealisedCol. I put them in the same method to be fast in copy/paste here)

```
        private void cbo_List_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Fill data_ListDisplay with the data set (datagridview) by changing the combobox value
            dt = tablecollection[this.cbo_List.SelectedItem.ToString()];
            data_ListDisplay.DataSource = dt;
            label3.Text = ($"Column Count{data_ListDisplay.Columns.Count}/Row Count {data_ListDisplay.Rows.Count}"); //Debug Purpose

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in data_ListDisplay.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("CR to validate"))
                    {
                        CrRealisedCol = cell.ColumnIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in data_ListDisplay.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (cell.Value.ToString().Contains("CR analysed"))
                    {
                        CrAnalysedCol = cell.ColumnIndex;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

where:
cbo_List is a combobox which is filled with all sheets in the workbook selected and both CrAnalysedCol and CrRealisedCol are declared as public as well.

label3.Text is always correct with both column and rows count.

Can someone please help me on that?

Thanks in advance

***EDIT 05/03/2020***
It look like that when i try to access to the DataGridView from another class by using

`Form_VVTool formmain = new Form_VVTool();`

dt becomes = null.
I suppose that it is because of InitializeComponent() which is called everytime the above code is executed.
What could be a way to preserve everything from Form_VVTool?
Thanks again

Comment: Did you try the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding. Look into `dt` ! (Also: Watch your spelling!)

Comment: What do you mean with “watch your spelling”? I’m, in the code? or my english (which by tue way it is not my first language).

Comment: post edit this afternoon